# Does Raspberry Pi 4 support AES hardware acceleration?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, hardware-acceleration, aes, aes-ni

I have Raspberry Pi 4 B (4GB version), I wonder if it supports AES hardware acceleration (so some special instruction set for CPU for faster encryption).

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set it says that architecture ARMv8-A (CPUs ARM Cortex-A30/50/70) supports AES hardware acceleration, and Raspberry Pi 4 B uses Broadcom BCM2711, Quad core Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit so CPU should support hardware acceleration, right?

Is there any special requirements to enable AES hardware acceleration on Raspberry Pi 4 B? Like special libraries or system images / kernel?

Comment: Looks like no: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243410

Comment: @Bob so is it hardware based? Change of kernel / system image doesn't help?

Comment: Not all that much concrete info but I did find someone mention that apparently ARM licences hardware crypto separately and it's quite possible that some A72s have it while others (incl. RPi4) don't.

Comment: @Bob that's same :/ because I need it, do you know some cheap SoC board with AES hardware acceleration?

Comment: @tomsk did you get a clue on that? Any RPi4 hat available?

Comment: S5P6818 has hardware crypto accelerator: DES/TDES, AES, SHA, MD5 and PRNG.

This SoC can be found in NanoPC-T3 Plus

Comment: Here's a [list](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135717/33476) of popular SoCs ranged by AES performance.